# Understanding CONSTRUCT templates

Tags: sparql, fuseki

I'm learning SPARQL right now, and I'm having trouble understanding the limits of CONSTRUCT templates. Normally everything works fine, just about the way I'd expect it to. However, my understanding breaks down when I start to make templates that don't semantically make sense. Here's an example:

I have the following data stored:

```
me:     a        foaf:Person .
foaf:mbox  rdfs:label  "Email" .
```

With a default template of `?s ?p ?o`, I obviously get that exact data back. If I go for something a bit nonsenical, like this:

```
CONSTRUCT {
    ?type ?labeled ?label
}
WHERE {
    me: a ?type .
    ?labeled rdfs:label ?label .
}
```

I get back this triple:

```
foaf:Person  foaf:mbox  "Email" .
```

This kinda makes sense to me, because there's three variables, and each has only one value it can bind to in the dataset. However, as soon as I switch the order of the variables in the template to be like this: `?type ?label ?labeled`, I get literally nothing back. Why is that? The template `?type ?labeled ?label` already breaks the original structure of the data and I still get something back, so why would `?type ?label ?labeled` be any different?

Comment: Isn't this obvious? A literal can't be in predicate position of an RDF triple

Comment: @AKSW Ah, that't the detail that I was missing. If that were obvious to me then I wouldn't be asking this question :)

Comment: I know, just kidding, sometimes (or quite often) it's so trivial that it is impossible to see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As noted by @AKSW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319082/understanding-construct-templates#comment91586860_52319082), literals can't be predicates. `"Email"` is a literal, and thus it couldn't be CONSTRUCTed into a predicate position.